# How to arrange display position of conten when using blade in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a folder in View:

```
resources -> view 
              - layouts
                    + master.blade.php
              - partials
                    + footer.blade.php
                    + header.blade.php
              - news
                    + show.blade.php
                    + list.blade.php
              - apartment
                    + show.blade.php
```

My code in `master.blade.php`:

```
<head>
  <script src="{{{ URL::asset('js/theme.min.js')}}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        @include('partials.header')
        @yield('content') 
        @include('partials.footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

In `news>show.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
  <div class="show-news">show all news at here</div>
@stop
```

In `apartment>show.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
  <div class="show-apartment">show all apartment at here</div>
@stop
```

In HTML file have structure like:

```
header

content
   - show slider image
   - show list news
   - show list apartment
footer
```

Because all file is define with `section('content')`.

I don't know how to arrange display position of `section('content') correctly with my HTML file.

I think it should be like:

In `news>show.blade.php`: @section('news')

In `apartment>show.blade.php`: @section('apartment')

In `master.blade.php`:

```
<head>
  <script src="{{{ URL::asset('js/theme.min.js')}}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        @include('partials.header')
        @yield('news') 
        @yield('apartment') 
        @include('partials.footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

But I see on almost project don't using like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another layout page that extends master page like this

master.blade.php

```
<head>
  <script src="{{{ URL::asset('js/theme.min.js')}}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        @include('partials.header')
        @yield('content') 
        @include('partials.footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

newlayout.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    @yield('news')
    @yield('appartments')
@endsection
```

And you can use this layout for pages like you described, for another you can use master